# Python mixin constructor not called when final class has no __init__

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, mixins, super

Final class user might want to create a a class composed from `Base` and `Mixin` (`Mixin` provides additional common functionality over a 3rd party library classes).

But the `Mixin.__init__` is not called when used as below. Only `Base.__init__` is called:

```
>>> class Base(object): #3rd party library class
...     def __init__(self): print "Base"
... 
>>> class Mixin(object): #my features useful as addendum for a few classes
...     def __init__(self): print "Mixin"
... 
>>> class C(Base, Mixin): pass
... 
>>> c = C()
Base
```

How to enforce calling both `Mixin.__init__` and `Base.__init__` in this scenario without requiring the user to remember to put a constructor with `super()` call in C class?

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def __init__(self): print "Base"
... 
>>> class Mixin(object):
...     def __init__(self): print "Mixin"
... 
>>> class C(Base, Mixin): 
...    #easy to forget to add constructor 
...    def __init__(self): super(C, self).__init__()
... 
>>> c = C()
Base
Mixin
```

Comment: `C.__init__` won't print both; it calls `Base.__init__`, which does not call any further functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't chain any method calls like this automatically, so you need to be disciplined and use cooperative inheritance correctly. If one class uses `super`, then all classes must use `super`. (This is a simple case, since none of the overriden `__init__` methods add any additional arguments. If they did, you would need to do some work to ensure that `object.__init__` never received additional arguments once it was called.)

Read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ before continuing.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base"
        super(Base, self).__init__()

class Mixin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Mixin"
        super(Mixin, self).__init__()

class C(Base, Mixin): 
    pass

c = C()
```

(This is also a perfect example of why you need to understand how `super` works, and *not* treat it as simple indirect reference to your class's base class.)

If you can't modify `Base` or `Mixin` to use `super`, then you'll need to define wrappers around them that can. The linked article explains how.